# Interface for editing JSON

Tags: json

I am new in writing my own data in JSON format so sorry if this question is silly.

I have my JSON with all data I need in my app. I will need to edit some of the data in future. I can open .json in Sublime and edit it like that but that is a crash waiting to happen. I wonder if there is some interface/app where you can upload your .json and then have like simple CMS with CRUD operations that change your .json after you make alterations in some user-friendly interface?

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Most of the languages have a JSON library that lets you work with JSON in a safe manner

Comment: I am using json for iOS (Swift) app.

Comment: I never worked with swift, but this looks like a good library for your purpose: [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Comment: Uh, I guess I didn't explain this quite right. I have an app. And I actually use SwiftyJSON but I don't ask about handling json in my app. I want some cms in which I can point to my json (this is on my server) file and then edit it as I please without using Sublime for example. Once I deploy an app there will be changes in my json and instead using Sublime for editing or other software I want to be able to edit it in some clean interface.

Comment: Oh, okay.  There are some online JSON editors which also validate your JSON to make sure it is formatted correctly. Have a look at [JSON Editor Online](http://jsoneditoronline.org)

Comment: I used that but that is not what I need. I guess that doesn't exist... Is there maybe some cms (cms in Wordpress-like) where can you point your .json file on your server and then perform various changes. And when you save your changes, your .json also changes and user sees different data in the app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106402/discussion-between-kira-arik-and-).